# Domain change: redirect 301 with htaccess does not work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I transferred my website from olddomain.de to newdomain.de and wanted to redirect every page of the old website to the new website (e.g. olddomain.de/contact -> newdomain.de/contact). When I enter the main page of the old website in the browser, I am redirected correctly but all other pages are not redirected.

I tried a lot of different redirect options and currently this one is implemented (the first IfModule already existed):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Does anyone know how to correct the .htaccess file, so that **all** pages of the website are being redirected?

#### EDIT:

I managed to get all sites redirected by putting some code at the top of the IfModule like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.de$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://newdomain.de/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Since this is working fine now, I wanted to change the address in the google search console but it says that the 301 redirection is not working. Does anyone have any suggestions here?

Comment: You need to change the order, these WP rewrites use the `L` flag and won’t let it get any further when they match.

Comment: Hey @04FS , I edited my question. Maybe you have any further suggestions? :)

Comment: What _exactly_ is “not working”? Please quote error messages from external systems or tools verbatim.

Comment: @04FS It's in German so I thought you would not want the exact message. The google search console says (translated): "Validation failed. A minimum of one of the necessary tests failed. Necessary: 301 redirection from the start page". It seems that google doesn't recognize the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

since your old site is not serving a WordPress instance anymore try removing the first part of your .htaccess file (you don't need it and may be causing the issue.

So let it just like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hey Lucas, thanks for you answer. I edited my question. Maybe you have any further suggestions?

Comment: Hi, as @04FS pointed out, the `L` flag is preventing anything else from happening. Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l